# Last character inside single quotes in code block missing syntax color

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I just came across this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy) and in Chrome with dark mode, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

It happens when the language of the code block is set to `lang-default`:

```
def a = "a string"
def b = 'another'
```

As you can see, the last character `r` in the second line ... shows up white.

UI bug?

Comment: If you look at the source, you'll notice it's ..`"= "<span class="hljs-symbol">'anothe</span>"r'`. It looks [like this in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5qxh.png) for me with my personal colour-style. So it's unrelated to dark/light mode. It's a highlight.js *feature* :D

Comment: ^, Looks just as wrong in light mode for me too, it's probably picking up the `r'` at the end as a raw string as groovy just uses the default highlighter (and indeed [groovy is not officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354591/684990))

Comment: Highlight.js maintainer here.  I've said in many places that `lang-default` should not exist (it's a SE invention). :-)  There is always a very good chance it is going to result in poor behavior (and doubly so the way it's currently implemented).  Since it does exist the best thing to do it avoid it.  Rely on tag hints or manual language hints instead and you'll get far better results.  But as Nick points out Groovy is tough since it's simply not supported/loaded by SE.  The best thing would be for SE to find a similar grammar and alias that to groovy for consistent behavior.